# Custom MKAnnotationView not staying centered on width change

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have an MKAnnotationView subclass being used to display information on a map. It has a UIImage as its background, and a UILabel on top of that image to display 4-5 characters of information.

Sometimes I need to update the annotation in the following manner:

1. Item annotation is pointing to gets favourited
2. UIImage gets changed to essentially the same one, but with a little heart icon on the right
3. Size of annotation changes to display favourite icon in addition to text

This flow works fine while favouriting it, but doesn't work when the item is removed from favourites. When unfavouriting, the annotation gets moved to the left slightly. I've been poring over our codebase and haven't been able to figure out why this is yet. I'd appreciate any ideas.